# Flutter download pdf from flask endpoint response

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm very new to flutter and am trying to receive a PDF sent from the backend

I have a python flask backend which sends a pdf using send_file using a get request:

```
return send_file(os.getcwd() + '/output.pdf', attachment_filename='output.pdf')
```

I'm trying to retrieve it in flutter using the following:

```
File file = new File(_localPath + "output.pdf");

try{
  await http
  .get(PDF_URL + "?property_id=153", 
  headers : {"Content-Type" : "application/json"})
  .then((response) async {
    await file.writeAsBytes(response.bodyBytes);

  });
} catch (Exception) {
  print(Exception.toString());
}
```

I don't know how to retrieve the PDF from the response because I have a react web app using the same backend and it successfully opens the PDF using this:

```
window.location.assign(response.url, '_blank')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For people struggling with it, the code in my question works and it does get the PDF from the url, I just wasn't accessing it correctly. I just added this line after the try catch block and it opens the PDF now:

```
OpenFile.open("_localPath" + "output.pdf");
```

Also thanks for your suggestion @Richard!

Answer (score 2):

Avoid mixing `await` with `then`. `await` allows you to write your code more serially. This approach will help you to debug, as you can see where your code reaches, print the response status code etc, etc.

```
final File file = File('${_localPath}output.pdf');
try {
  http.Response response = await http.get(
    '$pdfUrl?property_id=153',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
  );
  await file.writeAsBytes(response.bodyBytes);
} catch (e) {
  print(e);
}
```